# SVM: Scoring test data

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I am using `scikit-learn` and want to evaluate the `predicition` of a `SVM` on a testset.

```
from sklearn.svm import SVC
import numpy


dataset = numpy.loadtxt("training.txt", delimiter="\t")
X = dataset[:,0:15]
y = dataset[:,15:16]
y = y.ravel()

test_dataset_1 = numpy.loadtxt("test_14-15.txt", delimiter="\t")
X_test_1 = test_dataset_1[:,0:15]
y_test_1 = dataset[:,15:16]
y_test_1 = y_test_1.ravel()

model = SVC(kernel='linear', C=75) 

model.fit(X, y)

score_1 = model.score(X_test_1, y_test_1)
```

I get the ValueError:

> Found Input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [1682, 192]

My Training set has 1682 samples and my test set 192. But I just use the test set in the score-method. Why do I get this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
y_test_1 = dataset[:,15:16]
```

to this:

```
y_test_1 = test_dataset_1[:,15:16]
```

You are reading the original train data in `y_test_1` again, so its not matching the number of samples in `X_test_1`.